# Can I recover accidentally deleted data in SQL Server? If yes How?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Unfortunately I deleted one important record, and I didn't use the transaction. And I am using simple recovery model, can I recover my data? If yes, how? Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't recovery your data if don't have any backup, CDC or Database Audit.